# how to create one modal window and open it in different pages in php

Tags: php, html

I have a requirement in my application for creating modal window for List of Values from which user will select the value and selected value comes in the input text field. This is working fine if i am creating modal window in the same page. But i need this List of values in different pages, so is it possible to create this modal window for List of values and open it from different pages.
Code for opening modal window i am using is..

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal">
```

Code for modal window is ....

```
<div id="serviceModal" class="modal show fade" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title">Title</h6>
      </div>
      <input type="text" value="" name="rowid" id="rowid" style="display:none"/>
      <div class="modal-body pt-1">
        <div class="control-container pt-1">
          <table id="serviceTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover table-lightfont">
            <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              $servicedata=SelectData("table","code,description","","");
              $rownum=0;

              foreach ($servicedata as $servicedata) {
                echo "<tr id=$rownum>
                <td><input type='radio' name='serviceradio' id='serviceradio' value='{$servicedata['code']}'></td>
                <td>{$servicedata['code']}</td>
                <td>{$servicedata['description']}</td>
                </tr>";
                $rownum+=1;
              } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
          <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="button" name="selectservice" id="selectservice" class="btn btn-success"> 
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
          Select
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to create separate page for modal window and open this modal window from different pages as i need.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. The above is just the link you click on. The code to actually open the modal is most likely some javascript that get's triggered when you click on the link. Please add that and a description of what actually happens when you try it on other pages. It's very unclear what the issue is at the moment.

Comment: Hi, i will explain it further. actually i have one page for modal window with above code and i want to open this modal window from different pages instead of creating it on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by creating the modal window in separate php page and using it in my main page with include statement and it is working file.
whichever page i want to use this modal window i just need to use include statement.